# overlayfs root filesystem, cannot read /etc/mtab

Tags: disk-usage, cat, etc, overlayfs

I'm doing the following:

```
mkdir /tmp/upper /tmp/work
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/,upperdir=/tmp/upper,workdir=/tmp/work /

ls -l /etc/mtab
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 27. Feb 09:16 /etc/mtab -> ../proc/self/mounts

cat /etc/mtab
> cat: /etc/mtab: file or directory not found

umount /

ls -l /etc/mtab
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 27. Feb 09:16 /etc/mtab -> ../proc/self/mounts

cat /etc/mtab
> correctly prints mtab...
```

My question is, why is that so? What did I miss, regarding overlayfs?

Comment: Sounds like deja vu. Please check [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402052/overlayfs-over-read-only-rootfs-fail/402295#402295)
I hope this will help.